# Need Help Troubleshooting An Access Query

Tags: ms-access

I'm working in Access 365 for this project. I have a query:

```
SELECT inv_no, SalesID FROM GetOpenItems WHERE cust_id = '28017'
```

Which returns:

| inv_no | SalesID |
| --- | --- |
| 55414 | 30 |

I have another query:

```
SELECT SalesID FROM GetSalesStaff WHERE TRIM(SalesManager)=GetUserName()
```

Which returns:

| SalesID |
| --- |
| 30 |

Yet when I combine the two:

```
SELECT inv_no, SalesID FROM GetOpenItems WHERE cust_id = '28017' AND SalesID IN (SELECT SalesID FROM GetSalesStaff WHERE TRIM(SalesManager)=GetUserName())
```

I get an empty set.

I've used VarType() in test queries to determine that SalesID is vbString in GetOpenItems and vbString in GetSalesStaff, so they are both the same type.

I've tried adding the table names in the query as follows:

```
SELECT inv_no, SalesID FROM GetOpenItems WHERE cust_id = '28017' AND GetOpenItems.SalesID IN (SELECT GetSalesStaff.SalesID FROM GetSalesStaff WHERE TRIM(SalesManager)=GetUserName())
```

I've also tried converting SalesID on both sides of the 'IN' by wrapping in CLng(), same result. If I only wrap one or the other I get the expected type mismatch error, which supports that they are the same type currently.

I cannot for the life of me figure out why it's visually the same value yet somehow not evaluating the IN properly, and it's probably going to be something I'm staring at and glossing over. Any thoughts?

**ADDENDUM:**

Here is the GetUserName() function (which is really just a get method for a global var):

```
Public Function GetUserName() As String 
GetUserName = UserName 
End Function
```

The portion that sets the global var is inside another big function that is called on applicaton load:

```
UserName = Environ("USERNAME")
```

But I'm currently manually using Username = "mmoses" for testing.

That the query using this code returns 30 when run stand-alone makes me believe it should be evaluating to "IN (30)" in the larger query as well, so I don't suspect an issue in this bit...

**ADDENDUM 2:**

In response to questions in comments:
The immediate window shows 'mmoses' when the query fails and that Debug.Print is run, which is as expected.

mmoses is tied in the GetSalesStaff query to SalesID 30 (which is what `SELECT SalesID FROM GetSalesStaff WHERE TRIM(SalesManager)=GetUserName()` returns).

Additionally, I know it works with SalesID as text/number, but it's not an issue of a global variable losing value because I can immediately run the debug above and it returns the correct global value, and the query used inside the IN () bit runs on its own fine consistently

To test this I also rewrote all global vars to be TempVars and the same result is found.

The issue seems isolated to the odd quirk that:

```
SELECT SalesID FROM GetSalesStaff WHERE TRIM(SalesManager)=GetUserName()
```

Returns a single value, 30.

`SELECT inv_no, SalesID FROM GetOpenItems WHERE cust_id = '28017' AND SalesID IN (30)`

Returns the proper results, yet:

```
SELECT inv_no, SalesID FROM GetOpenItems WHERE cust_id = '28017' AND SalesID IN (SELECT SalesID FROM GetSalesStaff WHERE TRIM(SalesManager)=GetUserName())
```

returns nothing, even when all 3 queries are run back to back (and rerunning the previous queries still continues to return the proper results).

Comment: I had to test without GetUserName() function, just static criteria, and it works. Post the function code.

Comment: I have tried your function with SalesID as text and number. Get same results - query works. One issue with global variables is they lose value when code has unhandled runtime errors. TempVars do not.